# Android Signing Strategies: documentation contradiction?

Tags: android, google-maps, signing

I have one app published on Google Play. I'm writing a new application and I'm trying to figure if a need a new certificate for it, or if I can use the same certificate I used on the first app.

I need to use the Google Maps API on both apps. The [Google Maps API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#the_google_maps_api_key) says:

> "Applications that use the same certificate can use the same API key. However, the recommended practice is to sign each of your applications with a different certificate and get a different key for each one."

However, the [Android Tools documentaion](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#strategies) says the following:

> "In general, the recommended strategy for all developers is to sign all of your applications with the same certificate, throughout the expected lifespan of your applications."

So, is there a contradiction here? Should I use the same certificate or create a new one?

Answer (score 0):

That same page also says:

> The Maps API key is based on a short form of your application's
>   digital certificate, known as its SHA-1 fingerprint.

That's why you need a separate certificate for each separate key (if you decide to use separate API keys).

P.S. Situations like this are probably why your second quote says "**In general**, the recommended strategy...".

Comment: I see. So you're saying it's better to have two certificates because it's better to have two separate API keys, one for each app. And each key needs to have its own certificate. Is that right?

Comment: Ok, just one more question. The documentation says that _"Maps API keys are linked to specific certificate/package pairs"_. So given that the package names are different, the resultant API keys should be different too, right? Even if the certificate is the same.